# Tikz How to set the default arrow color and size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

I can use

```
\tikzset{every node/.style={red, draw=none}}
```

to set defaults for nodes

but how do I do it for arrows. I would like to be able to set defaults for thickness and color so I do not have to set the same over and over.

Comment: like this, for example : `\tikzset{>={Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 3,red]}}`

Comment: @AndréC How do I set the line of the arrow though, not just the tip? I want to change the color of the entire arrow(including the shaft) from black to something else.

Comment: please add a minimal working example

Comment: The width of the arrow is the same as that of the drawn line and is fixed with the same options (thick, thin, etc).

Comment: @AndréC All I want to do is set the color of the arrow to something other than black. You've given me a solution to set the tip of the arrow... I WANT TO DO THE ENTIRE ARROW! It is not complicated. `\tikzset{>={blue, Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 3,red]}}` does not set the entire arrow to blue. Nor does `\tikzset{-={blue}}`.

Comment: Following @AndréC: `\tikzset{draw=green, >={Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 3]}}`